# Visa requirements for Hungary for a prospective student pilot

Tags: visas, schengen, hungary

**Background:** I have enrolled in a private pilot school to get flying credentials in Hungary. The training will take 5-6 months, and thereby I believe I'll need a visa to stay or enter/exit Hungary frequently as I'll be staying longer than 90 days per 180 day period.

**Research:** I've looked at various website such as:

- [Hungary Schengen Visa Application Requirements](https://www.schengenvisainfo.com/hungary-visa/)
- [Hungary / Hungary Guide / Visas & Permits / Short-stay visas](https://www.justlanded.com/english/Hungary/Hungary-Guide/Visas-Permits/Short-stay-visas)
- [Study in Hungary](http://studyinhungary.hu/living-in-hungary/menu/formalities/visa.html)

**Question:** What visa would I require when I travel to Hungary to complete my pilot training (circa 5-6 months). I am already currently enrolled to start mid next year.

**About me:** I am an Australian national.

Comment: Are you planning to go directly from nothing to ATPL with no pauses? You certainly don't need to do it all at once. You could do whatever training you can fit into 90 days, leave for at least 90 days, and then return to finish up. Keep in mind, also, that it may take you longer (or shorter) than six months!

Comment: @MichaelHampton  That's the plan - a solid study plan and lots of caffeine :P - I I can't afford to take breaks for 3 months, every 3 months :/

Answer (score 1):

Well, you should first check at the Embassy of Hungary in Australia (https://canberra.mfa.gov.hu/eng), then contact your pilot school for further instructions and advice. You will probably need a Hungarian visa that allows stays over 90 days. Giving you are attending a special learning school, you could get a student-vise or working-vise maybe.

Or just try a few workarounds detailed here (https://www.nomadicmatt.com/travel-blogs/how-to-legally-stay-in-europe-for-more-than-90-days/), but I'm not sure they apply to your trip arrangements.